# How do I create a ViewModel [ReactiveUI] property in AvaloniaUI with custom getter/setter?

Tags: c#, mvvm, reactiveui

I have a AvaloniaUI WPF application (which uses ReactiveUI).
I'm having difficulty create a [Reactive] property with a custom getter/setter.

**Consider the following code snippet:**

```
class SomeValueClass : IValue {}

private IValue? ValueStubFoo;
private IValue? ValueStub;
[Reactive] public IValue? CustomValue 
{ 
    get
    {
        if (ValueStub is null)
        {
            if (ValueStubFoo is SomeValueClass valueStub)
            {
                // Clone() is a method on SomeValueClass
                ValueStub = valueStub.Clone();
            }
        }
        return ValueStub;
    }
    set { ValueStub = value; } 
}
```

**At compile time I get the following exception:**

> Error     Fody: An unhandled exception occurred: Exception: Failed to
> execute weaver C:..\weaver\ReactiveUI.Fody.dll Type: System.Exception
> StackTrace:    at InnerWeaver.ExecuteWeavers() in
> C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:line 222    at
> InnerWeaver.Execute() in
> C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:line 113 Source:
> FodyIsolated TargetSite: Void ExecuteWeavers() Sequence contains more
> than one matching element Type: System.InvalidOperationException
> StackTrace:    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)    at
> ReactiveUI.Fody.ReactiveUIPropertyWeaver.Execute()    at
> ReactiveUI.Fody.ModuleWeaver.Execute()    at
> InnerWeaver.ExecuteWeavers() in
> C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:line 186 Source:
> System.Core TargetSite: TSource
> Single[TSource](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSource], System.Func`2[TSource,System.Boolean])

I've isolated to the [Reactive] tag on the CustomValue property.
If I remove the tag, it builds correctly.
It looks like there's an issue with [Reactive] properties with custom accessors.

How do I get this to work with custom getters/setters?

Comment: Fody is not for that case. Use https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-models/#read-write-properties

Comment: I was able to get this to work by keeping the custom accessors in place and using WhenAnyValue().Subscribe(OnValueChanged) to update/change the property value.